# WPF: Referencing app-wide resources in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, code-behind

I have made my own custom converter which given a string returns a `Brush`. Now I'm able to return constant brushes such as `Brushes.Red` etc., but I really want to use my own colors which I have defined in an application-wide resource.

How do I reference application-wide resources from my own custom converter class? I'd use `FindResource` but as I said, this is from my own converter class, not a window or control.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/resources-and-code

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If these are defined on your Application, you can use [Application.Current.FindResource()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.findresource.aspx) to find them by name.

Comment: `TryFindResource()` may be a better solution as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37955433/4465708).

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Reed's answer, if your resource dictionary is a standalone XAML file, you need to ensure it is (as Reed says) "defined on your Application."

**App.xaml**:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication10.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Dictionary1.xaml**:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <TextBlock x:Key="k_foo" Text="FOO" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The `Build Action` on this dictionary XAML file can be set to `Page`. It should be in the same directory as the App.xaml file.