# How do I reference a StaticResource in code-behind?

Tags: winrt-xaml

In XAML I do it like this:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}" />
```

How do I do the same thing in code-behind?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The page-level Resources object has the ability to find local, app-level, static, and theme resources. This means you simply do this:

```
foo2.Style = this.Resources["NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle"] as Style;
```

Best of luck!

Comment: How to do it just for background color? XAML: `<ContentPage.Resources><ResourceDictionary><Color x:Key="Accent">#100c00</Color></ResourceDictionary></ContentPage.Resources>` xaml.CS: `btnLogout.BackgroundColor = this.Resources["Accent"] as BackgroundColor;` result in editor error
> the type or namespace BackgroundColor does not exist...

Comment: There's no such thing as "BackgroundColor " in "XAML", you must use "Background" for that purpose. @s3c

Comment: Got null as @Josh Bowden explains in his answer. I recommend that instead of this.

Answer (score 23):

During design-time, it seems that trying to resolve a "system resource" using `Resources[key]` will fail to find the resource and will return `null`. For example, to get the base `Style` for a `TextBox` using  `Resources[typeof(TextBox)]` will return `null`.

Instead, use `TryFindResource(key)` since this will first try  `Resources[key]` and then will otherwise try searching through the "system resources" and will return what you're looking for (as per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.tryfindresource(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) and [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Application.cs,387)).

In other words, try this instead:

```
var style = Application.Current.TryFindResource(key) as Style;
```

Comment: This is for WPF only - doesn't exist for Xamarin

Answer (score 16):

Try with this

```
Application.Current.Resources["key"]
```

Comment: What are the benefits of your approach over the established answers on this thread?

Comment: @JeremyCaney local Resources don't contain StaticResources for me.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a generic helper class that can be used.  The advantage of going this route, is tha tyou will be able to use the same helper to get other types of resources (like Brushes, or DataTemplate for example)

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static T Get<T>(string resourceName) where T : class
    {
        return Application.Current.TryFindResource(resourceName) as T;
    }
}
```

And how you would use in code:

```
yourButton.Style = Helper.Get<Style>("NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle");
```

And if you wanted to get a brush resource you'd use

```
ItemTemplate = Helper.Get<DataTemplate>("MyDataTemplate");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in the ViewModel, you wont be able to use the answer above.

To bring up to date the answer from Eternal21, you could so this:

```
public static T Get<T>(string resourceName) 
{   
    try
    {
        var success = Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue(resourceName, out var outValue);

        if(success && outValue is T)
        {
            return (T)outValue;
        }
        else
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Note the where clause is missing here. I didn't want to restrict it to classes, so I could use it with Color too which is a struct... so removed it.